Dynamically update View size information in SwiftUI
I am building my first app in SwiftUI. One of the required functionalities is for the user to be able to make annotations on an image. The image has to be panned and zoomed. However I also need to keep track of its absolute location on the screen ánd keep track of relative locations of the annotations (relative to the image as a whole).
I am having great trouble with getting the absolute and relative positions of the image on the screen. By now I have tried a dozen different configurations for GeometryReader, however that only returns information of ít's bounds/frame within it's parent, but not of the Views (in my case, the Image) inside of the GeometryReader itself. I can't figure out a way to dynamically return these properties. I have now given up and will try to keep track of changes (DragGesture and MagnifyGesture) and apply those to the initial values of the image, but in my opinion this is less favourable. I hope this community can help!
I have tried (among other things) the following relevant ideas:
It started out with trying to use GeometryReader:
struct MyView: View { 
    // Inputs 
    var imageName: String 

    // States 
    @State private var imageSize: CGSize = .zero 
    @State private var scale: CGFloat = 1.0 
    @State private var offset: CGSize = .zero 
    @State private var zoomAnchor: UnitPoint = .center 
    @GestureState private var magnifyBy = 1.0 
    @GestureState private var translateBy: CGSize = .zero 

    // Body 
    var body: some View { 
        
        let image = Image(imageName) 

        ZStack { 
            GeometryReader { geometryProxy in 
                image 
                    .resizable() 
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit) 
                    .scaleEffect(scale * magnifyBy, anchor: zoomAnchor) // Apply both the persistent and gesture scale 
                    .offset(x: offset.width + translateBy.width, y: offset.height + translateBy.height) // Combine persistent and gesture offset } 
                    .gesture( 
                        SimultaneousGesture( 
                            MagnifyGesture() 
                                .updating($magnifyBy) { value, gestureState, _ in 
                                    gestureState = value.magnification 
                                } 
                                .onEnded { value in 
                                    scale *= value.magnification 
                                }, 
                            DragGesture() 
                                .updating($translateBy) { value2, gestureState2, _ in 
                                    gestureState2 = value2.translation 
                                } 
                                .onEnded { value in 
                                    offset.width += value.translation.width 
                                    offset.height += value.translation.height 
                                } 
                            ) 
                        ) 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        }
    } 

As described in my introduction this does not return the size and location of the View contained inside the GeometryReader though.
I also tried the background with a clear Color trick that I see floating around on the internet, however this does not update dynamically when pinching or dragging (There may be a curly bracket to many or few because of copy pasting):
struct MyView: View { 
    // Inputs 
    var imageName: String 

    // States 
    @State private var imageSize: CGSize = .zero 
    @State private var scale: CGFloat = 1.0 
    @State private var offset: CGSize = .zero 
    @State private var zoomAnchor: UnitPoint = .center 
    @GestureState private var magnifyBy = 1.0 
    @GestureState private var translateBy: CGSize = .zero 

    // Body 
    var body: some View { 
        
        let image = Image(imageName) 

        ZStack { 
            image 
                .resizable() 
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit) 
                .scaleEffect(scale * magnifyBy, anchor: zoomAnchor) // Apply both the persistent and gesture scale 
                .offset(x: offset.width + translateBy.width, y: offset.height + translateBy.height) // Combine persistent and gesture offset } 
                .background( 
                GeometryReader { geometry in 
                    Color.clear 
                        .onAppear { 
                            imageSize = geometry.size 
                        } 
                    } 
                ) 
                .gesture( 
                    SimultaneousGesture( 
                        MagnifyGesture() 
                            .updating($magnifyBy) { value, gestureState, _ in 
                                gestureState = value.magnification 
                            } 
                            .onEnded { value in 
                                scale *= value.magnification 
                            }, 
                        DragGesture() 
                            .updating($translateBy) { value2, gestureState2, _ in 
                                gestureState2 = value2.translation 
                            } 
                            .onEnded { value in 
                                offset.width += value.translation.width 
                                offset.height += value.translation.height 
                            } 
                        ) 
                    ) 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    }
} 

Another way I tried this trick was using a View Extension and modifier:
struct SizeCalculator: ViewModifier { 
    @Binding var bounds: CGRect 

    func body(content: Content) -> some View { 
        content 
            .background( 
                GeometryReader { proxy in 
                    Color.clear // we just want the reader to get triggered, so let's use an empty color 
                        .onAppear { 
                            bounds = proxy.frame(in: .global) 
                        } 
                        .onChange(of: proxy.size) { 
                            bounds = proxy.frame(in: .global) // Update bounds when size changes 
                         } 
                } 
            ) 
        }
    } 

extension View { 
    func saveSize(in bounds: Binding<CGRect>) -> some View { 
        modifier(SizeCalculator(bounds: bounds)) 
    } 
} 

However this also refused to update the bounds/frame dynamically, both when used as a modifier to the image and when called as a method in for example an .onChanged(of:scale) structure. I also tried ideas which I don't fully understand but found online like:
private func updateImageBounds(proxy: GeometryProxy) { 
    // Update bounds based on the proxy's frame 
    DispatchQueue.main.async { 
        self.imageBounds = proxy.frame(in: .global) 
        print("Bounds updated -> minX: \(imageBounds.minX), maxX: \(imageBounds.maxX), minY: \(imageBounds.minY), maxY: \(imageBounds.maxY), width: \(imageBounds.width), height: \(imageBounds.height)") 
    } 
} 

Finally I also tried making the Image a UIImage, which seems to provide greater access to it's dynamic properties, but I got all kinds of problems here with compatibility if I remember correctly. I may have tried 20 other variations of the ideas mentioned above which I haven't all saved or remembered, but you get the idea. Is there some way to get these properties in a dynamic fashion? I am very curious what the combined knowledge on here can come up with!

Consider the nature of SwiftUI, working with the coordinate spaces is the least advantage it has over UIKit, if any. Maybe consider creating this feature in UIKit and wrap the entire component in UIViewRepresentable to make things easier.
